# R Extract value in column based off another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I am calling from within a for loop. I have various site names that the for loop is runnning through. I want to take the location name and extract a corresponding number from another data frame.

This is my very basic code:

```
for (site in dataList) {
tubeTop <- diverInfo[Need to reference correct column here]
}
```

"dataList" is a list of three tables. Each table is named and this matched to a location in the target data frame (screenshotted below).
table names = 'crose mere', 'sweat mere', 'whattall new'.

"diverInfo" data frame looks like this below. I want to take the site i.e. location in the table and extract the corresponding mAOD value. i.e. when the data frame in the for loop is called 'Crose Mere', I want to extract the value 87.350.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over `names(dataList)` instead of `dataList`, assuming the list is a named list and the names are unique? Eg:

```
for (sitename in names(dataList)) {
 site = dataList[[sitename]]
 tubeTop <- diverInfo[diverInfo$Location==sitename,'mAOD']
}
```

Or you adapt your answer above to:

```
for (i in seq_along(dataList){
  siteName <- names(dataList)[i]
  tubeTop <- diverInfo[diverInfo$Location==siteName ,'mAOD']
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried, but it just returns 'numeric (empty)'.

Comment: could be that the table names are lower case but the `Location` variable has title case?  They would need to match exactly.

Comment: They do match. I've checked for that.

Comment: Sorry I forgot I was using `data.table` syntax without thinking about it!  I've fixed my answer and added an alternative to yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best method so far. I feel like there should be a better way.

```
i = 1
for (site in dataList) {
  siteName <- names(dataList)[i}
  i = i + 1
  tubeTop <- diverInfo[diverInfo$Location==siteName ,]['mAOD']
  tubeTop<- tubeTop$mAOD[1]
}
```